# What is the meaning of `movq` and `movw` in initializing array in C?

Tags: c, assembly

I have an initialization of array in C like that:

```
char buf[10]={0};
```

And I show its assembly code in gdb, it shows up:

```
char buf[10]={0};
0x0000000000400591 <+20>:    movq   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
0x0000000000400599 <+28>:    movw   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
```

I know the offset base on`%rbp` is allocating space, but I don't know what is the meaning of `movq` and `movw`? Seems that it not allocate the space only, initialization also be done at the same time. But why the offset is 0x20 or 0x18?

Comment: You should tag this question with the architecture on which you are using assembly. This looks like x86-64 (probably applicable to 32-bit as well), so you should tag it x86 (if I am correct about that).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These instructions do not allocate space. By the time they are executed the space (on the stack) is already allocated. All they do is initialize that space with zeros.

On your platform local variables are stored at negative offsets from `rbp`. Your array has 10 bytes in it and is stored at offset `-0x20` from `rbp`. The

```
movq   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
```

instruction sets the first 8 bytes of `buf` to zero (a "quad word" - `q` in `movq`). The

```
movw   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
```

instruction sets the remaining 2 bytes of `buf` to zero (a "word" - `w` in `movw`).

Note that `-0x20 + 8` is `-0x18`. That's where `-0x18` came from.

```
      |----------------- buf -----------------|

    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--     ---+---
...   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |   ...    |   ...
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--     ---+---
      ^                               ^                  ^
      rbp - 0x20                      rbp - 0x18         rbp

                    zeroed              zeroed
                      by                  by 
      |------------- mowq ------------|--movw-|
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your ascii graph is so clearly. I forgot what the `quad word` means, it has 8 bytes!

Comment: The x86-64 System V user-space ABI has a red-zone, so you can use up to 128B of space below `%rsp` without modifying `%rsp` first.  i.e. it's already considered allocated, and won't be asynchronously clobbered by signal handlers or anything else.  Probably the OP's function never modifies `%rsp` explicitly at all.